# Encoding problems with ajax form submission

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, forms

I am using a simple tutorial of a hopefully not outdated method to submit a form with ajax which can be found [here](http://www.simonerodriguez.com/ajax-form-submit-example/)

My concern (and problem) is that when I submit special characters (like the greek letters *αβγδ* etc) they are encoded but I cannot decode them to look right...

I tried the online string [encoder/decoder](http://coderstoolbox.net/string/) in order to find which method is the correct and what I got is that a simple URL decode in UTF-8 is fine. Unfortunately, this doesn't work with my example and the characters stay the same.

A string I want to decode is this

```
%u03C3%u03B5 %u03B5%u03C5%u03C7%u03B1%u03C1%u03B9%u03C3%u03C4%u03CE %u03C0%u03BF%u03BB%u03CD
```

And the result shall be

```
σε ευχαριστώ πολύ
```

I am working this form in php and javascript. The js file that does the encoding and probably causes the problem can be found [here](http://www.simonerodriguez.com/wp-content/plugins/downloads-manager/upload/ajaxsbmt.js)
As for the rest of the scripts, the form is the same as in the example and the response php is just echoing the `_POST` values.

Any help will be much appreciated! Thanks guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `encodeURIComponent()` in javascript before sending data to your php script. It should automatically be decoded correctly in php.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
unescape('%u03C3%u03B5 %u03B5%u03C5%u03C7%u03B1%u03C1%u03B9%u03C3%u03C4%u03CE %u03C0%u03BF%u03BB%u03CD');
```

#### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vn5Xj/)

Comment: is there any equivalent function in php? I googled it and urldecode() is presented as the php version of unescape which is giving me wrong result...